# using if condition in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables as shown below with columns:

```
Table A
a, b, c, id 

Table B 
d, e, f, g, h, id
```

Now I need perform a query basically I will get a id from user, so I need to check if that id is present in table A or table B. So the record will be present in any of one table

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE id = 123 
OR 
SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE id = 123
```

So the response will be either columns of tableA or columns of tableB. But I can't perform a union since the columns should be equal among two tables.

So it's basically a if condition, how can I get  the desired  output in Snowflake.

And using if is the best optimized approach or any other way is there

Comment: A SQL query must return a *fixed* set of columns. If you want all columns from the table where the id is found, you cannot do this in a single query.

Comment: but if i give select * which means its should return all isn't

Comment: yes `select *` means all columns. Hence my comment.

Comment: I remvoved the `postgreql` tag, because Snowflake is a completely different DBMS product than Postgres.

Comment: @GMB i didn't understood clearly, can you explain how can i approach this one since i am a beginner to db

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sure, but snowflake use mysql kind of query structure isn't should i add mysql tag

Comment: No, please don't. Just because the "pretend" to be similar, doesn't mean they are the same. You are using Snowflake, so that's the only product that should be tagged.

Comment: sure, so any idea how to resolve this

Comment: @GMB any idea on this

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all` -- assuming the types are compatible.  Just pad the smaller table:

```
select a, b, c, null as g, null as h, id 
from a
where id = 123
union all
select d, e, f, g, h, id 
from b
where id = 123;
```

If you want the columns separated, then a `full join` accomplishes that:

```
select *
from a full join
     b
     using (id)
where a.id = 123 or b.id = 123;
```

Comment: But the full join takes too much time, one table has 46 and one table has 34 columns.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS . . . I am not aware that the performance of a `FULL JOIN` is directly related to the number of columns in the underlying tables.